# What is wrong with this argument on $U_q(sl(2))$? What is missing to make it precise?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let us define $U_q(sl(2))$ as the algebra with four generator as usual 
$$K\,K^{-1}=K^{-1}K=1,$$$$K\,E\,K^{-1}=q^{2}E,\,K\,F\,K^{-1}=q^{-2}F,\\EF-FE=\frac{K-K^{-1}}{q-q^{-1}}.$$
I want to easily show that can be thought as a deformation of $U(sl(2))$. So the easiest thing to do is to think $K=q^H$ and derive for example
$$K\,E\,K^{-1}=q^{2}E,$$
which becomes
$$q^H\,E\,q^{-H}=q^{2}E,$$
deriving by $q$ we obtain
$$Hq^{H-1}\,E\,q^{-H}-q^{H}\,E\,Hq^{-H-1}=2qE,$$
and letting $q \rightarrow 1$ (but let us suppose that $q$ is never 1 just to avoid the problems in the definition of the algebra). As limit you get the usual commutation relations
$$HE-EH=2E.$$

Now my questions: Since I never saw this derivations in any book I assume something is wrong with this procedure, I would like to understand what is wrong with all this step taken? What is missing to make this argument rigorous? As said before let us suppose that $q$ is never equal to 1 to avoid that type of problem that I'm already aware of...

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should try to explain carefully what you mean by "deriving by $q$. Why, precisely, is $\frac{d}{dq}q^H=Hq^{H-1}$? And what do you mean by $H$? It is not an element of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$.

Comment: @David Hill thank you for your insights! I guess I could define the exponential by the formal series involving $q$ and take formally the derivation. Why $H$ is not an element of $U_q(sl(2))$? $H$ it's just the base element of $sl(2)$. Can you be more specific on what could go wrong and/or some hints on how to make it precise?

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming your conclusion.

Comment: If you take $q = e^{\hbar}$ so $K = e^{\hbar H}$, and expand everything in series you can also prove that $\lim_{\hbar \to 0} U_{\hbar} = U$. But as David Hill said, it's only an heuristic or informal argument, if you want to make it rigourous you need to put a topology and look at some kind of completion. I don't really know the details.